# Where is the error in getting this to recognize the relations?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm working on a code that requires a combing of a 1000 number array(nr), the numbers being random and all between 0 and 100. I've worked up this so far, but i can't get it to read them properly, nor give me an output.

```
clc %Clear console
load m05.mat %load given file

%% Initialization
satindices=[];
satvalues=[];

%% Processes
for i = numel(nr)
    if nr(2:end) == nr(1:end-1)
        satvalues=i;
    end
end

%% Output
fprintf("The indices of nr that satisfy the relations are %i\n",satindices)
fprintf("The values of the indices of nr that satisfy the relations are %i \n",satvalues)
```

Here's the actual prompt that came with the challenge: Write a program that will use for loop to find all the elements in vector nr that have the same value as  the previous element of the same vector. Generate two result vectors: one with all indices of elements satisfying the condition, and another one with values of elements that satisfy the condition.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, are you simply checking if the previous element matches the current element in vector `nr` for each element position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Checking If Left-Neighbouring Element is Equivalent

Below is a for-loop script that checks if the previous element is equal to the current target element. The values and indices are saved only when the if-statement is true this also triggers the increment of `i`. Variable `i` is used as an indexing variable to control the index/cell to store the resultant values. Some things to keep in mind:

• `fprintf()` → Typically prints one value for each placeholder (`%f`,`%d`, etc.). Can be called multiple times in a loop to print an array.

• The for-loop implemented in your script seems to only traverse to one value `numel(nr)` which will evaluate to `1000`. Typically, an ending value and incrementing value is used in for-loops.

**General Form:**

```
for Start_Value = 1: +Increment: End_Value

end
```

---

### Full Script:

```
clc;
Vector_Size = 1000;
Minimum = 0;
Maximum = 100;
nr = randi([Minimum Maximum],[1 Vector_Size]);

satindices = [];
satvalues = [];

i = 1;
for Index = 2: numel(nr)
    
    %If the previous element is equal to the current element%
    if nr(Index-1) == nr(Index)
        satvalues(i) = nr(Index);
        satindices(i) = Index;
        i = i + 1;
    end
end

fprintf("The indices of nr that satisfy the relations are: \n");
disp(satvalues);
fprintf("The values of the indices of nr that satisfy the relations are: \n");
disp(satindices);
```